# ListView updating data from another thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have activity where Im viewing data in listView. But I have to fill data from another thread. As you can see in following code. On every data change I'm calling handler message which triggers notifyDataSetChanged(). When I'm updating data less than 1 change per second it works ok, but when Im changing data faster It throws IllegalStateException. Is there any chance to catch this exception?

Is there any more clear solution how to update data from another thread?

full code link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nxyac1xd88g2y71/TestListThreadFill.zip

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView list;
    private TestAdapter adapter;
    public static MainActivity magic;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        magic = this;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        list = (ListView)findViewById( R.id.list);

        adapter = new TestAdapter( getApplicationContext());
        new FillThread().execute((Object) null);

        Data.getInstance().addHandler(this, new Handler(){
            @Override public void dispatchMessage(Message msg) {
                update();
                super.dispatchMessage(msg);
            }
        });

    }

    public void update(){
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override protected void onResume() {
        list.setAdapter( adapter);
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Data continer:

```
public class Data extends Vector<DataItem> {
    private static Data instance = null;
    private HashMap< Object, Handler> handlerList;

    public Data() {
        handlerList = new HashMap< Object, Handler>();
    }

    public static Data getInstance(){
        if( instance == null)
            instance = new Data();
        return instance;
    }

    @Override public synchronized boolean add( DataItem object) {
        boolean result = super.add(object);

        for( Map.Entry< Object, Handler> handler : handlerList.entrySet())
        {
            handler.getValue().sendEmptyMessage( 0);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public synchronized void addHandler( Object object, Handler handler){
        handlerList.put( object, handler);
    }

    public synchronized void addHandler( Handler handler){
        addHandler( handler, handler);
    }

    public synchronized void removeHandler( Object object){
        handlerList.remove( object);
    }
}
```

Data filler thread:

```
public class FillThread extends AsyncTask{
    @Override protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        while( true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Data.getInstance().add( new DataItem( "L", "TOP", "BOTTOM"));
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
05-23 13:20:23.900  25260-25260/com.example.TestListThreadFill E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131034115, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.example.TestListThreadFill.TestAdapter)]
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1549)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2170)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13846)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4466)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13846)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4466)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13846)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4466)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13846)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4466)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13846)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4466)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2149)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1907)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1127)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4606)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:567)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:536)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-23 13:20:30.923  25260-25265/com.example.TestListThreadFill D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
05-23 13:20:30.923  25260-25265/com.example.TestListThreadFill D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x4000016E, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
05-23 13:20:31.421  25260-25265/com.example.TestListThreadFill D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
05-23 13:20:31.421  25260-25265/com.example.TestListThreadFill D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x17, id=0x4000016F, flags=0x0, dataLen=0xC
05-23 13:20:31.429  25260-25265/com.example.TestListThreadFill D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
05-23 13:20:31.429  25260-25265/com.example.TestListThreadFill D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x40000170, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
05-23 13:20:31.429  25260-25265/com.example.TestListThreadFill D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
05-23 13:20:31.429  25260-25265/com.example.TestListThreadFill D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x40000171, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
```

Comment: I suppose you need 'onPostExecute' in FillThread to inform Main UI Data has changed

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty clear the error message :
`Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.`

You could try something like this :

```
public class FillThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, DataItem> {
    @Override
    protected DataItem doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return new DataItem();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(DataItem dataItem) {
        // call an update method that adds the dataItem and notifies the adapter
    }
}
```

Comment: But I need task which never ends, so I can not use onPostExecute.